# Python convert x,y data to latitude & longitude data

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, geolocation, trigonometry

This code is a function which then runs it through a for loop with an if statement (not included for brevity but basically it lets me separate some factory output data by machine and location).  The function is designed to convert x and y data i am given in meters from a known lat and long position and convert that to a new lat and long.  I do this using Pythagoras and then a formula i found on SO.

It works without error but the math fails as it adds more or less a degree of longitude to the output.  It should produce data very similar to the reference location as it is never more than about 50 meters away from it.

here is a section of the JSON from which the data is taken for interest

```
"id": "b4994c877c9c",
"name": "forklift_0001",  <---forklift data used in IF statement
"areaId": "Tracking001",
"areaName": "hall_1",
"color": "#FF0000",
"coordinateSystemId": "CoordSys001",
"coordinateSystemName": null,
"covarianceMatrix": [
    0.47,
    0.06,
    0.06,
    0.61
],
"position": [
    33.86,    <---position data converted from known lat/long, X then Y.
    33.07,
    2.15
   ],
    "positionAccuracy": 0.36,
    "positionTS": 1489363199493,
    "smoothedPosition": [
        33.96,
        33.13,
        2.15
```

and here is the code

```
import json
import pprint
import time
import math

file_list = ['13_01.json']

output_nr = 1

def positionToLatLon( position ):
    posx = position[0]
    posy = position[1]
    R = 6371 #Radius of the Earth
    brng = 1.57 #Bearing is 90 degrees converted to radians.
    d = math.sqrt((posx*posx) + (posy*posy)) #Distance in km from the lat/long  #Pythagoras formula
    lat1 = math.radians(40.477719)#reference lat point converted to radians
    lon1 = math.radians(16.941589)#reference long point converted to radians
    lat2 = math.asin(math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) + math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng))
    lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),
    math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))
    lat2 = math.degrees(lat2)
    lon2 = math.degrees(lon2)
    result = []
    result.append(lat2)
    result.append(lon2)
    return result
```

So it runs without any errors but the output is incorrect, it adds more or less a degree of longitude and so moves the whole result about 60m east making the analysis no good and I cannot see why.

I've looked for a different formula but no luck and my maths isn't good enough to see if I am using an incorrect trig function or something.

All help appreciated.

Comment: would you help me and tell me what is the `position` input ? is that the `"position"` key in your json ? and could you tell me what is the expected output to debug this.

Comment: `60nm` is 60 *nanometers*. Surely you don't mean that. But -- what do you mean? Also, the earth isn't flat, so it isn't clear why you are trying to use the Pythagorean theorem to compute distances between points on the surface of the earth.

Comment: You need to take care with what the parameters (i.e. which projections) were used for the origin coordinate transformation and replicate them exactly. Different projections can easily result in a difference of over 100 meters. Maybe you can use something like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python to check your results?

Comment: 1.  Yes, the position input comes from the JSON.  the expected output is is 1 degree of longitude further east.
2.  60nm is is 60 nautical miles, the base unit of degrees of latitude. The math is supposed to all for the earth being round.  Pythagorus calculates the distance from an origin and then the radial math allows for curvature (if it's correct math)

Comment: The units seem confusing. You say the distances are in meters but your code seems to treat them as kilometers. If the distances are in meters then such small amounts are swamped by glib estimates like `R = 6371` and `1.57` for `math.pi/2`. If they are in kilometers, then ignoring the curvature of the earth in computing distances isn't justified and in any event saying that a forklift is 33.86 kilometers away from a known location doesn't seem like a very sensible way to locate a machine within a factory. It would help if you made your question a [mcve] and say what the expected output is.

Comment: Thanks John.  I am going to look at the units as that might be the problem.

Comment: Radius is in Kms, and d is in meters if you do `R = 6371000` then you get the same results exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Change brng = 1.57 to brng = (math.pi/2). This is not a suitable estimate, and is likely the source of some if not all of your error